# Why does Aperture tag my photos with the wrong address?

Tags: apple-aperture

I have a number of photos that I have manually tagged with a location. (They did *not* have any GPS data associated with them automatically, as I took them with a camera without such facilities.) I have given them a street address, but Aperture labels them with a *different* street several blocks (about 2 miles) south of where I tagged them. When I open the same library in iPhoto, they have the correct address associated with them. Does Aperture have some sort of location database it uses to associated geotagged coordinates with a street address? Can I clear this database? Or is there another way to make Aperture actually associate the photos with the correct address?

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that in Aperture it's not recognizing the full address, but only a city/state? If that's the case, then the geotagging is likely centering within a geographic range, getting you close to the right address, but not quite close enough.